# How to alternate moves with player and AI

Tags: c

I just made a game, and in the beginning I prompt the user to type which color they want the cpu to be. There are 2 colors, black and white, and if user types computer to be White, the user will move first, else the computer will move first. I tried to implement the computer being white first, but I didn't seem to have much luck.

```
if (color == 'W') {
    int player = 0;
    int computer = 0;
    printBoard(boardgame, size);

    player++;
    computer += 2;
    do {
        if ((player + 1) % 2) {
            playerMove(oppositeColor(color), boardgame, size);
            player++;
            numbermoves++;
        }
        if (computer % 2) {
            computerMove(color, boardgame, size);
            computer++;
            numbermoves++;
        }
    } while (numbermoves < size * size);
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What happens? What do you see? What do you not see? Most importantly, what have you tried to do to debug it?

Comment: There should be no difference between a computer move and a player move. It is just a move with a color. For the user, you ask for input [of the color]; for the computer, you calculate a move [of the color].

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference between a computer move and a player move. It is just a move with a color. For the user, you ask for input [of the color]; for the computer, you calculate a move [of the color], for example:

```
int numbermoves = 0;
char playerColor;

printf("What color do you want (W/B)?");
scanf ("%c", &playerColor);
do {
    if ((numbermoves%2)==0) { // white
        if (playerColor=='W')
             askMove ('W', &move);
        else calcMove('W', &move);
        putMove('W', &move);
    }
    else {
        if (playerColor=='B')
             askMove ('B', &move);
        else calcMove('B', &move);
        putMove('B', &move);
    }
    numbermoves++;

} while (numbermoves < size * size);
```